# ADT doesnt sync Android Private Libraries with libs folder

Tags: android, adt

[image]

Things i tried:

1. Clean Up
2. Refresh
3. Rename libs then rename it back to libs
4. right click on Project -> Android Tools -> Fix project properties
5. [image]
6. closed project and reopened it
   none helped, what should i do to correct this?
7. i noticed that if i remove the android lib projects from the android import screen ADT syncs the libs  folder and when i readd them it removes the libs, is it a bug on ADT?

[image]

[image]

Comment: I assume you are working with Eclipse. Please explicitly **close the project** and re-open it.

Answer (score 0):

Right click your project, click properties, go to "[java build path](http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Freference%2Fref-properties-build-path.htm)" choose tab "order and export" ensure android private libraries is ticked.

Answer (score 0):

***When you removed the old files some references and dependencies might not have removed***

---

- **Step1**: Delete all the libraries from `libs` folder
- **Step2**: Go to `Project` -> `Rightclick` -> `Properties` -> `Java Build Path` -> `Libraires`
  *Delete android private libraries Explicitly*

---

`There are two places that the reference to the previous project needed to be deleted from, not just one. It had to be taken out of both the "Projects" tab on "Build Path" and out of "Project References" in the project properties`

---

- **Step3**: Finally paste the new libraries again into libs folder
- **Step4**: Clean the project and run